# User authentication in RoR - should it be in the User handler or its own Authentication handler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm writing user authentication (sign in/sign out) right now in RoR and am wondering if its better to put it in the User handler, or make its own handler.

Anyone who has used RoR, what's your take on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it so that any model can utilize the authentication, thus create it like a gem.

However, i would highly recommend that you use a ready made solution, like Devise.